# RxJS: Emit value when delay between source emits too long

Tags: rxjs

I have a stream which emits at 1Hz. Once in a while, there is a delay between the emitted items of some seconds, let's say 10 seconds. I want to create an observable which subscribes to the source, and everytime the delay between the items is too long (e.g. 5s), it shall emit an item of another type. However, when the source emits normal values again, it should emit the source.

```
-O-O-O-O-O----------O-O-O-O---|---> source
-O-O-O-O-O----X-----O-O-O-O---|---> observable
```

I thought, that I could use `timeoutWith(delay,of(X))` in this case, but this would unsubscribe from the source, loosing the rest of the stream.

When I use `switchMap(O => of(O).timeoutWith(delay, of(x))` to have a disposable stream of Os, it does not timeout as the inner observable hasn't been created yet.

Any ideas?

**FINAL SOLUTION**

This is the solution, which in the end is what I need:

```
this.sensorChanged
    .pipe(
      mapTo(SensorEvent.SIGNAL_FOUND),
      startWith(PositioningEvent.SIGNAL_UNAVAILABLE),
      switchMap(x => concat(of(x), timer(5000).pipe(mapTo(PositioningEvent.SIGNAL_LOST)))),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    )
```

The missing link was the startWith() which prevented the switchMap from emission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but this should do the trick:

```
const result$ = source$.pipe(
  switchMap(o => concat(of(o), timer(5000).pipe(mapTo(x))))
);
```

Comment: no, this does not work. the inner observable will only be available when the source emitted something. if it does not emit, the inner observable will not run.

Comment: @Dennis you said: "everytime the delay between the items is too long, it shall emit an item of another type.". If there is a delay **between** items, it means the source has emitted an item.

Comment: okay, to be more precise: the timeout may also happen, when the source never emitted any item.

Comment: but you gave me the right direction. I edited my question with the final solution.